# Connect to Gmail via phpmailer

Tags: php, email, authentication

I trying connect to my e-mail located in gmail.com. I want create contact form. I have created form contact in HTML. Now I try use phpmailer class to connect. I show my code:

```
<?php
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : false;
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : false;
$topic = isset($_POST['topic']) ? $_POST['topic'] : false;
$message = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : false;

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

if(isset($_POST['send_message'])){
    include "../phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php"; // include the class name
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "mypassword";
    $mail->SetFrom("myemail@gmail.com");
    $mail->AddAddress('myemail@gmail.com','MyName');
    $mail->Subject = "Here is the subject";
    $mail->Body = "This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>";
     if(!$mail->Send()){
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    else{
        echo "Message has been sent";
    }
}
?>
```

When I try run this code I geting the following errors:
http://pastebin.com/R7PBZDei
How fix it?

Comment: did you read the errors? your username/password are incorrect. it even TELLS you a url to go to for answers...

Comment: no, you haven't, or you'd have gone to the url in the error, and learned what to do: `Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754`

Comment: just because your password works from your home machine doesn't mean it's going to work from wherever your server is located.

Answer (score 1):

```
$mail->Host        = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port        = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure  = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth    = true;
$mail->Username    = "user@gmail.com";
$mail->Password    = "pass";
```

Greetings